# Preventing CSS of Jquery Dialog content from being applied to main window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

In my web application, I have written a cross-domain ajax call which is fetching an HTML page from a different domain. This newly fetched page is being rendered in a jQuery dialog using the following code `$('#previewDialog').html(response).dialog('open');`
This renders the response properly in the dialog. However, the response (HTML page) also has some CSS styles in it. These styles (generally BODY, INPUT etc) are getting applied to my main window (parent page) and distorting the complete view of the page.

When the dialog with the HTML page opens, the view of the parent page is completely distorted because of the CSS used in the HTML page (response of AJAX call) which gets applied to all the components. And when I close the Dialog, the parent page gets back into shape.

Is there anyway, by which I can prevent the CSS of the HTML page which is being displayed in dialog, not get applied to my parent page?

Comment: Yes! It is actually another application which sends us HTML pages based on a request we send. These HTML pages are generated on the fly by that other app.

Comment: Are you able to edit the source of the loaded app/dialog?

Comment: The dialog which is displaying the pages is written by me. So I have full control over the app containing the dialog. But the other app which is serving me dynamic HTML pages, I have no control over its code or the pages it sends. I am a mere receiver and I need to display em as it is to the end user.

Comment: One option is, If I use iFrame instead of Jquery dialog. But then I am doubtful about the cross domain call and how to render the HTML pages. Moreover, in iFrame I may not be able to unbind click and onSubmit events.

Comment: If you want to use an iFrame, that is possible, as long as the service you are calling does not require POST params - as for binding events, you can access the iFrame's elements with jQuery as well (AFAIK).

Comment: is there anyway this can be done without an iFrame?

Comment: Yes, but you need to have whoever is making the content you are fetching, rename their styles.

Comment: Correction, you cannot access content with jQuery/JS from an iFrame that is from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial answer: have everything from the page that you pull in be wrapped in a div with a class not used elsewhere.  modify the .css for that page so that it only applies to elements within a div of that class.

Edit: If you cannot control the css of the origin page, things become somewhat more complicated.  your problem, though, is that you're injecting the HTML (including the css link) directly into your page.  Instead, try the following:

- Grab the HTML for the other page.  Place it into a div off to the side that you're not using for anything else using the html() command.
- Go into that div using the jquery DOM commands.  Grab the portion of the page inside of the troublesome links, and pull it over to the `$('#previewDialog')` location.  Destroy the contents of the working space div.  If there is javascript or css that you need to preserve, have it entered (modified, if necessary - like with div wrappers) elsewhere in the page.

Now, this only works if the pages that you're being fed don't have their css or javascript changing with any frequency.

An alternate version of the same thing - while you have it as a response (a string format) use string manipulation tools to excise the css reference, rather than using DOM commands to pull what you need out of it.

More complicated/difficult version of the same thing (though somewhat more robust): Use string commands to slice out the css references (as with the alternate version) and then make another call using that css reference to acquire the .css file.  Use string commands on the .css file to add in the div-wrapper limits as initially described, then insert it elsewhere on the page as an internal style sheet.

Comment: I cannot modify the CSS of that page. Although I can wrap it around a DIV and add a new class, but the HTML page is generated on fly using velocity templates in another app which is inaccessible by me. The HTML page itself contains the style element. Is there a way I could fetch all the styles and add the class in them?

Comment: Have updated answer based on feedback.  I believe that this will give you what you need, but I realize that I may not be being entirely clear.  Please feel free to ask for clarification if what I have written doesn't make perfect sense.